# shortcut for repetitive else if statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I have to write repetitive else if conditions like:

```
  if (d_hand[1]==1){
    state=score(p_hand)-1
  } else if (d_hand[1]==2){
    state=19+score(p_hand)
  } else if (d_hand[1]==3){
    state=39+score(p_hand)
  } else if (d_hand[1]==4){
    state=59+score(p_hand)
  } else if (d_hand[1]==5){
    state=79+score(p_hand)
  } else if (d_hand[1]==6){
    state=99+score(p_hand)
  }
```

Do you know if it could be written more efficiently/shortly?
I thought about doing a loop of if but it would be less efficient since every statement would have to be examined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No `ifelse` at all:

```
state <- score(p_hand) + 20 * d_hand[1] - 21
```

Comment: What is if its `d_hand[1] = 2.5`?  Maybe you'd need a `if` statement to check the number is in a certain set.

Comment: What if the OP would have mentioned that. This answer obviously applies to his MRE. There might be other users with similar tasks where it is reasonable to check if such arithmetic might be applicable. If not, upvote one of the other answers :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit ashamed i didn't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a lookup table.

```
add <- c(-1, 19, 39, 59, 79, 99)
state <- add[which(1:6 == d_hand[1])] + score(p_hand)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `switch` from base, or dplyr `case_when` :

```
library(dplyr)
state <- case_when(d_hand[1]==1 ~ {score(p_hand)-1}, 
          d_hand[1]==2 ~ 19+score(p_hand), 
          d_hand[1]==3 ~ 39+score(p_hand), 
          d_hand[1]==4 ~ 59+score(p_hand),
          d_hand[1]==5 ~ 79+score(p_hand), 
          d_hand[1]==6 ~ 99+score(p_hand)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This logic is very close to @Martin.

```
state <- score(p_hand) + 20*(d_hand[1]-1) - 1
```

**EDIT**
I had thought to gain some performance benefit but I had missed one point. I'll share details of `microbenchmark` performance later. But performance of @Martin is better than mine (which obvious).

Comment: Please, explain how your answer is different to [Martin Schmelzer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49676502/3817004) and why you think this is the "optimum way". Perhaps, have you done some benchmarking to confirm? Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe Sorry good point. Actually, I thought logic-wise it was clear representation and some benefits by keeping  value low in operation. But had missed one point that my answer is `NOT CORRECT`. To correct it I have `subtract`  another `-1` out of it. It will be slower. Let me do some bench-marking. Perhaps this answer dont stand on its own.